# res.downalod changing the name of .tiff file while downloading if fileName contain forward slash

Tags: node.js, file, express, tiff

I am using express res.download to download the file from the server location as below-

```
res.download('path', 'report a/b/c.tiff')
```

on downloading above file name is getting changed to c.tiff.
what will be the possible reason and how to get downloaded file as report a/b/c.tiff only.

Answer (score 0):

/ is a globally user for differentiating directories hence forth OS will not allow / in file names as well as for directory.

In Windows you will get the below error,
[image]

likewise linux OS also uses the same. But we can use '\' for creating files. Allowed chars in Linux,

Double your \, like this: \, so that your shell does not interpret the backslashes from your filename as escape characters.

Escape " and ', like this: \", \', so that your shell interprets the double quotes as part of the filename.

Escape $, like this: \$, otherwise your shell will think you're using a variable.

Escape ? and *, like this: \?, *

Hence you download has only c.tff

Comment: I tried but it's still giving c.tiff when downloading